# Program freezing when trying to send emails with smtp

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp, freeze

I'm currently having a bad problem with my program, I'm trying to learn how to send emails with smtp and I wrote this code to do this. When I try to click on button1 the program freezes and nothing happens.
PS: Obviously that I changed the email and password to "email" and "password" before post this.
PS2: I'm writing my code in portuguese so, anything that you may don't understand just consider as a variable or "x".

Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Net;

namespace Inicio
{
    public partial class Email : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=digital wallet;User ID=root;password=");
        public Email()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SendEmail()
        {

            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos", "Erro",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                int i = 0;
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select EMAIL from conta where EMAIL = @email  and LOGIN = @login ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login ou email inválidos", "Erro",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from CONTA where LOGIN = @login";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    string senha = "";
                    string email = "";

                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        senha = reader.GetString("SENHA");
                        email = reader.GetString("EMAIL");
                    }

                    reader.Close();

                    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "outlook.com";
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
                        smtp.Credentials = netCred;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                        using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("email", email))
                        {
                            msg.Subject = "Recuperação de senha.";
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.AppendLine("A sua senha é atual é: " + senha + Environment.NewLine);
                            sb.AppendLine("Obrigado," + Environment.NewLine);
                            sb.AppendLine("Digital wallet. " + Environment.NewLine);
                            msg.Body = sb.ToString();
                            msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                            smtp.Send(msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendEmail();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, post an answer. Don't edit the solution into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are running in a GUI enviroment. Events must return a quickly as possible, otherwise the GUI is "locked up". Disk and network activity in particular is prone to be long running. You have to apply some form of Multitasking (and move the long running operation into that alternate Task) to avoid the GUI locking up.

As a beginner, I would advise to using the BackgroundWorker for Multitasking. Async...await is more advanced.

Edit: Here is my WinForms+BackgroundWorker example code. It should help get you started with using it properly.

```html
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
 {
  //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
  int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
  pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
  tbPrim.Text = "";

  //Start processing
  bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
 }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
 {
  bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
 }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
 //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
 //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
 BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

 //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
 List<int> Primes = new List<int>();
 

 //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
 for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
 {
  //Report progress
  thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
  bool isNoPrime = false;

  //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
  if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
  {
   //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
   e.Cancel = true;
   break;
  }

  //Determin if this is a Prime Number
  for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
  {
   if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
    isNoPrime = true;
  }

  if (!isNoPrime)
   Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
 }

 //Tell the progress bar you are finished
 thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

 //Save Return Value
 e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
 pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
 this.Refresh();

 if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
 {
  //Show the Result
  int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

  StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (int Prim in Primes)
  {
   sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
  }

  tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
 }
 else 
 {
  tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
 }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing your sql-query, connecting to the smtp-server and transfering the mail data to the server takes time. Since you execute all that stuff in the UI-Thread, your form freezes.

Add a `BackgroundWorker` to your form, add the event handlers for `.DoWork` and `.RunWorkerCompleted` and add the SQL and SMTP stuff to the `DoWork` function.

On Button1Click you start the BackgroundWorker with `.RunWorkerAsync`. Pass an string array to this function with you TextBox1 and TextBox2 contents. You need to do that since you can't access those elements from the `DoWork` function. Optionally you can check with `.IsBusy` if the worker is already active. After starting the worker you should lock the UI or display a message or something like that to tell the user that a background process is running. Do this from the Button1Click function.

Then modify the `.DoWork` function to extract the passed string array. You do that by accessing the passed `DoWorkEventArgs.Arguments` and cast them to the type you passed to `RunWorkerAsync` - to string-array. Swap the TextBox access to the array values.

In the `RunWorkerCompleted` function you have to unlock the UI.

Start reading about BackgroundWorker and you can use the progress-reporting function to notify the user about the progress, something like 'gathering sql data, connecting to smtp server, transfering mail data, done'...

Comment: I left the program running and I receive an excepction that says the operation time limite exceed.

Comment: Operation Time limit Exceeded implies something went wrong on the Networking side. Wrong Credentials or Protocoll. Server not found. Something like that. You need to look into the inner Exceptions to figure out what exactly. The risk of running into some timeout like that is one reason to always put Networking stuff into Multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

Luan Teixeira,

You should take a look into the [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx). That will solve your problem.

To demonstrade what I am saying. Check out this code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async Task SendEmail()
    {

        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos", "Erro",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            await Email.SendEmail();

            MessageBox.Show("Nice");
        }
    }
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await SendEmail();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class Email
{
    public async static Task SendEmail()
    {
        await Task.Delay(15000);
    }
}
```

You can write something in textbox1 and textbox2 and click the button. Wait for 15 seconds (I am simulating a really huge task that may take 15 seconds). Meanwhile you can see that the User Interface is not freezing. You can move the window around. After 15 seconds you are going to receive a "Nice" message.

That's because in my code the huge task is not running in the GUI thread.

Hope it helps
Kind regards
Daniel

Comment: Thanks for that, I will take a look to this.

Answer (score -1):

Change the timeout property. So, smtp.Timeout = 0; Should work!